# Design approach to use in Android when several activities need to connect to a service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have a class that starts a Bluetooth reading thread and another that receives/decodes what's read from that port and produces some output logs depending on the information read.

In my design, those 2 components form a service for my application (multiple activities) from where I would like to start/stop getting the output logs on a continuous basis (typical frequency of 2-3 logs per second).

My questions:

1) Should I derive from Service or IntentService.  The doc says about IntentService: "This is the best option if you don't require that your service handle multiple requests simultaneously".  This may be my case since the main activity will start/stop the service...

2) What would be the appropriate way to catch the service events?  Does the BroadcastReceiver is appropriate for this type of communication?

3) I may need to occasionally send some stuff to the Bluetooth port.  So, I'll have to pass information from my application to the service.  Does the PendingIntent should be used for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I derive from Service or IntentService

`IntentService` is designed for discrete tasks, not stuff that would run indefinitely until the user manually stops it. I would use `Service`.

> What would be the appropriate way to catch the service events? Does the BroadcastReceiver is appropriate for this type of communication?

That is certainly one approach. You might use the `LocalBroadcastManager` from the Android Support package to reduce overhead and keep everything private to your app. Have your activities register a receiver in `onResume()` and remove it in `onPause()`. The foreground activity will then be notified of events.

> I may need to occasionally send some stuff to the Bluetooth port. So, I'll have to pass information from my application to the service. Does the PendingIntent should be used for that?

No, I would have the activity simply send a command to the service via `startService()`, with the data to be passed included in extras on the `Intent`. If you have data that cannot be packaged as extras, you may need to consider binding to the service, so you can get a richer API, though this makes configuration changes more annoying.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. About your third answer: using intent in startService will be OK when I start the service but I'm not sure that I can use that for passing information to my service once it is already started, right?

Comment: @Danuc: The primary job of `startService()` is to send commands to the service. You can do that once, twice, or a million times. It *also* happens that `startService()` will create an instance of the service (if one does not already exist) and marks it as running (until `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`).

Comment: OK... So the startService can act as a handler for sending commands to the service. Then, it's my business to do the appropriate thing depending on the intent. Subject closed!